# How do i sort a date column in EXTJS

Tags: sorting, date, extjs, grid

I have a problem with my date sorter. I get my date out a XML file and looks like this:

```
<date>18-10-2011</date>
```

my store is this:

```
 Ext.define('blockedList', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [{
        name: 'sourceFile',
        type: 'text',
        mapping: 'sourceFile'

    }, {
        name: 'summaryFile',
        type: 'text',
        mapping: 'summaryFile'

    }, {
        name: 'date',
        type: 'date',
        mapping: 'date'

    }, {
        name: 'total',
        type: 'float',
        mapping: 'total'

    }]
});
```

But when i sort on date it is not doing the correct sorting. If i have these dates: 1-1-2011, 3-1-2011 and 1-2-2011 it sorts like this:
1-1-2011
1-2-2011
3-1-2011

how can i get this sorting working like it should?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you need to set the `dateFormat` within the field. For example I have dates returning from a JSON request and the field has `dateFormat: 'MS'` attribute.

I'd give [this a read on Ext's dateformats](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.Date). Hope that helps.